# Map dependencies in JSON structure

Tags: javascript, json, database, data-structures, structure

I am currently building a web tool which enables the user to generate a package of options in the form of a String. To select which options he wants he uses a form with different inputs (radio, checkbox) which is generated from a `dictionary.json` that currently holds all available options and their codes in the following format (subject to change):

```
[

    {
        "id": 0001,
        "title":"foo",
        "type":"radio",
        "options":[
            {
                "bar":"",
                "foo":"489",
                "foobar":"489+490"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 0002,
        "title":"something",
        "type":"check",
        "options":[
            {
                "everything":"M016",
                "evenmore":"M139"
            }
        ]
    },

    [...]
```

As you can see it is basically a small database. The problem is that the options depend on each other so if `foo` is `foobar` it might determine that `something` is definitely `evenmore` and can NOT be changed to `everything`. **How would I map these dependencies in the `dictionary.json` so that the generated form can reliably grey out options that are determined by other choices?**

The structure has to be flexible so new dependencies can be inserted and would generate the new form reliably or validate existing outputs against them. There could also be options that depend on multiple other options. I can't think of a smart way of saving these dependencies and I wonder if JSON is the right format to go with here.

Any tips or ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Joi: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi. You can validate almost any JSON object with really complex and extensible joi schemas.

Comment: @AnandUndavia thanks for your comment. I'm not sure how this would apply here as the only validation that takes place is if a rule set (String) is "allowed" as in "it doesn't contain rules that exclude each other"

Comment: Are the options exclusive to a single object or to the `"type"`? Eg. can the option `"bar"` appear on other objects and/or types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to save every option as one object which stores all the options which will be excluded if that option is selected.
So your JSON could look like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0001,
        "title":"foo",
        "type":"radio",
        "options":[
            {
                "bar":"",
                "excludes": []
            },
            {
                "foo":"489",
                "excludes": []
            },
            {
                "foobar":"489+490",
                "excludes": [
                    {
                        "id": 0002,
                        "options": [
                            "everything"
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 0003,
                        "options": [
                            "apple",
                            "cherry"
                        ],
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 0002,
        "title":"something",
        "type":"check",
        "options":[
            {
                "everything":"M016",
                "excludes": []
            },
            {
                "evenmore":"M139",
                "excludes": []
            }
        ]
    },

    [...]
```

Everytime an option is selected you would have to check their excludes list and diable all those options for the specific fields.
To improve the usability you could check there is only one option left for a field, select this option and then disable the whole field.

**EDIT:**
Additionally you could save a `isExcludedBy` field to each of the options.
The `everything` option of `id 0002` would then look like this:

```
"isExcludedBy": [
    "id": 0001,
    "options": [
        "foobar"
    ]
]
```

This would be kind of redundant, but depending on what you want your UI to show, it could save you some computing time.

Answer (score 1):

A possible simple solution (which answers your question):

```
// dictionary.json
{
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 0001,
            "title":"foo",
            "type":"radio",
            "options":[
                {
                    "bar":"",
                    "foo":"489",
                    "foobar":"489+490"
                }
            ]
        }
        // etc.; same as before
    ],
    // this is it:
    "dependencies": [
        [["0001", "foobar"], ["0002", "evenmore"]],
    ]
}
```

`dependencies` here consist of pairs of [*path to option in `options` that implies another option*, *path to the implied option*].
You could make a `Map` data structure out of this directly (the implying options are keys, the implied are values).

This assumes that one option can imply only one other option (but it still allows for *options that depend on multiple other options*).

You could of course easily extend that like so:

```
[["0001", "foobar"], [["0002", "evenmore"], ["0003", "namaste"]]]
```

This would mean that `"0001"/"foobar"` implies both `"0002"/"evenmore"` and `"0003"/"namaste"`. But perhaps YAGNI. :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to model the domain you're actually expressing, and generate the form based on that.  For example, we know that apartments have street numbers, and apartment numbers, whereas houseboats don't even have streets.

```
{
    "dwelling": {
        "type": "houseboat",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
    }
}
```

or

```
{
   "dwelling": {
       "type": "apartment",
       "street": "Beech St.",
       "street_number": 123,
       "apartment_number": 207,
   }
}
```

By modelling the domain rather than the form, you can write rules that apply beyond the form, and you won't have to develop a mini-language for expressing form dependencies.

Comment: How would you address the dependencies with this approach?

Comment: @omel09 you don't need to express dependencies with this approach.  You'd have one routine for rendering houseboats and another for rendering apartments.  The houseboat rendering wouldn't include street number, and the apartment rendering wouldn't include longitude.